# Checking if a string is a number on iPhone

Tags: iphone, string, floating-point, numbers

How can I check if an input string is a number like `x.y`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
NSString *nameRegex =@"[0-9]+\\.[0-9]$"; 
NSPredicate *nameTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", nameRegex]; 
BOOL isDecimalNumber=[nameTest evaluateWithObject:string];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more solution.

```
NSString *str = @"123456";
NSCharacterSet *decimalSet = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
BOOL valid = [[str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: decimalSet] isEqualToString:@""];
```